# How to collect the text displayed on the screen of Android device

Tags: android, text, mobile, screen, extract

I have a project that needs to collect the common words and phrases used on the mobile device whether it is a system text or an application text. Is it possible to get the contents of all the text that is being displayed on the Android device screen at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't, and to be able to do so would present a fairly big privacy vulnerability.